# Duplicate static variable initialization in C++

Tags: c++, linux, static, dlopen

I build a shared library "libMyLibrary.so" with a class "MyClass" that contains a static variable of type "MyClass".
Then I build an executable "MyLibraryTest" that I link against "libMyLibrary.so".
The main program uses "dlopen" to load dynamically a ".so" given as an argument.

While building, the library and executable are generated in a directory, say, "buildDir/bin".
Then I install the library into "installDir/lib" and the executable into "installDir/bin" (removing the runtime path from the executable).

When I run "buildDir/MyLibraryTest buildDir/MyLibrary.so" with LD_LIBRARY_PATH=buildDir, everything is fine.

But when I run "buildDir/MyLibraryTest installDir/lib/MyLibrary.so" with LD_LIBRARY_PATH=installDir/lib, a very strange thing occurs :
- The static variable's constructor is called *twice* (once before dlopen, once during dlopen)
- At the end of the execution, the destructor is called twice, and this results into a crash.

Here is my code :

MyClass.h

```
#ifndef _MyClass_h__
#define _MyClass_h__

#include <string>

class MyClass
{
private:
    static MyClass myStaticObjOfMyClass;
public:
    MyClass(const std::string& name, bool trace);
    virtual ~MyClass();
private:
    std::string myName;
    bool myTrace;
};

#endif // _MyClass_h__
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <iostream>

MyClass MyClass::myStaticObjOfMyClass("myStaticObjOfMyClass", true);

MyClass::MyClass(const std::string& name, bool trace) : myName(name), myTrace(trace)
{
    if (myTrace) std::cout << "MyClass::MyClass(name=" << myName << ", address=" << this << ")" << std::endl;
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    if (myTrace) std::cout << "MyClass::~MyClass(name=" << myName << ", address=" << this << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

MyLibraryTest.cpp

```
#include <MyClass.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const std::string sharedLibraryFullName((const char*)argv[1]);

    // std::cout << "Try to load library " << sharedLibraryFullName << std::endl;
    void* handle = NULL;
    std::cout << "dlopen(" << sharedLibraryFullName << ")" << std::endl;
    handle = dlopen(sharedLibraryFullName.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR : Could not load shared library " << sharedLibraryFullName << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "OK, shared library " << sharedLibraryFullName << " is now loaded" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here are the compilation and link commands :

```
/usr/local/bin/g++  -DMyLibrary_DEFINED -DMyLibrary_EXPORTS  -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC   -o CMakeFiles/MyLibrary.dir/MyClass.cpp.o -c MyClass.cpp
/usr/local/bin/g++ -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG  -shared -Wl,-soname,libMyLibrary.so -o ../bin/libMyLibrary.so CMakeFiles/MyLibrary.dir/MyClass.cpp.o
```

And at last here is what happens in the second case (duplicate initialization of the static variable) :

```
MyClass::MyClass(name=myStaticObjOfMyClass, address=0x7fa710cabb40)
dlopen(/tmp/Install/MyLibraryTest/lib/libMyLibrary.so)
MyClass::MyClass(name=myStaticObjOfMyClass, address=0x7fa710cabb40)
OK, shared library /tmp/Install/MyLibraryTest/lib/libMyLibrary.so is now loaded
MyClass::~MyClass(name=myStaticObjOfMyClass, address=0x7fa710cabb40)
MyClass::~MyClass(name=��ObjOfMyClass, address=0x7fa710cabb40)
*** glibc detected *** /tmp/Build/MyLibraryTest/Release/bin/MyLibraryTest: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000cfb330 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x322f275dee]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x322f278c3d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__cxa_finalize+0x9d)[0x322f235d2d]
/tmp/Build/MyLibraryTest/Release/bin/libMyLibrary.so(+0x1076)[0x7fa710aab076]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1325638                            /tmp/Build/MyLibraryTest/Release/bin/MyLibraryTest
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 1325638                            /tmp/Build/MyLibraryTest/Release/bin/MyLibraryTest
00ce9000-00d1b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
322ee00000-322ee20000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 545634                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
322f020000-322f021000 r--p 00020000 fd:00 545634                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
322f021000-322f022000 rw-p 00021000 fd:00 545634                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
322f022000-322f023000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
322f200000-322f38a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 545642                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
322f38a000-322f58a000 ---p 0018a000 fd:00 545642                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
322f58a000-322f58e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 545642                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
322f58e000-322f590000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 545642                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
322f590000-322f594000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
322fa00000-322fa02000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 545709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
322fa02000-322fc02000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 545709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
322fc02000-322fc03000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 545709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
322fc03000-322fc04000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 545709                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3230600000-3230683000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 545684                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3230683000-3230882000 ---p 00083000 fd:00 545684                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3230882000-3230883000 r--p 00082000 fd:00 545684                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3230883000-3230884000 rw-p 00083000 fd:00 545684                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7fa70c000000-7fa70c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa70c021000-7fa710000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa7102e7000-7fa7102e9000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1320668                    /tmp/Install/MyLibraryTest/lib/libMyLibrary.so
7fa7102e9000-7fa7104e8000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 1320668                    /tmp/Install/MyLibraryTest/lib/libMyLibrary.so
7fa7104e8000-7fa7104e9000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 1320668                    /tmp/Install/MyLibraryTest/lib/libMyLibrary.so
7fa7104e9000-7fa7104ed000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa7104ed000-7fa710503000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 708322                     /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa710503000-7fa710702000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 708322                     /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa710702000-7fa710703000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 708322                     /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa710703000-7fa710704000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa710704000-7fa710883000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 708539                     /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fa710883000-7fa710a83000 ---p 0017f000 fd:00 708539                     /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fa710a83000-7fa710a8d000 r--p 0017f000 fd:00 708539                     /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fa710a8d000-7fa710a8f000 rw-p 00189000 fd:00 708539                     /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fa710a8f000-7fa710a94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa710aa8000-7fa710aaa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fa710aaa000-7fa710aac000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1325633                    /tmp/Build/MyLibraryTest/Release/bin/libMyLibrary.so
7fa710aac000-7fa710cab000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 1325633                    /tmp/Build/MyLibraryTest/Release/bin/libMyLibrary.so
7fa710cab000-7fa710cac000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 1325633                    /tmp/Build/MyLibraryTest/Release/bin/libMyLibrary.so
7fa710cac000-7fa710cad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff2fc61000-7fff2fc76000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff2fde5000-7fff2fde6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
./test_dyn_libs.sh: line 21: 30880 Abandon                 (core dumped) ${BuildDir}/MyLibraryTest ${InstallDir}/lib/libMyLibrary.so
--- End of tests
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: You didn't include compilation and link commands for MyLibaryTest. The problem could be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.
As Todd said, I forgot to include the link command for MyLibraryTest. Here it is :

```
/usr/local/bin/g++  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/MyLibraryTest.dir/MyLibraryTest.cpp.o  -o ../bin/MyLibraryTest -Wl,-rpath,/tmp/Build/MyLibraryTest/Release/bin: ../bin/libMyLibrary.so -ldl
```

The problem was related to the RPATH. If I do not use the -Wl,-rpath option any more, the test works fine !

I use CMake to build my projects, and found this :
https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling. Now I use the following command in my CMakeLists.txt, which removes the -Wl,-rpath link option.

```
set (CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH ON)
```

Answer (score 3):

As Todd Fleming commented, I think probably you have mistakenly linked your MyLibrary.so into your test executable when you compile the test executable.

You can use *ldd* to check whether your executable has been linked to the library.

I have tried your code on my ubuntu linux with exactly the same compiling options. For the test executable, that MyLibrary.so should not be linked, so I didn't link it. It turns out the bizarre behavior didn't occur.
When I linked the test executable with MyLibrary.so, the result is exactly what you said (including the glibc dump). It is not too surprising, because when you install your library to another path, the loader will regard it as another totally irrelevant library, thus double-loaded.

PS: What surprised me is that these 2 singletons are placed in the same memory location, it's somewhat unbelievable. I also tested it (the case when the executable is linked to the library) on my mac os x, it turns out that on os x, these 2 instances have different memory location. It's more reasonable to me.

**UPDATE:**

About why these 2 instances have the same memory location, actually it's a feature of symbol resolution in Linux. Please see the comments for details. Thanks n.m. for pointing out.

Comment: This does not explain the phenomenon. dlopen should not normally load a second copy of a shared object, no matter how the first copy was brought in.

Comment: This could happen if the executable physically contains MyClass.o i.e. is linked with it staically.

Comment: Yes, a second copy will not be loaded, which means if you link the library and dlopen it, only one copy is loaded. But if you change the path/name of the library and dlopen it, it's another story.

Comment: It would be clearer if you look at the glibc dump, there are 2 libMyLibrary.so loaded with different paths.

Comment: Hmm. The dlopen man page says it should not depend on paths being used. The soname should identify the lib, not the path. I'll try to test it..

Comment: OK got it. Soname doesn't matter, the file itself does (inode?) If both paths point to the same file (e.g. with symbolic links) everything works OK. If you have two separate files, even identical, it crashes as described.

Comment: As for why there's only one copy of the static variable: it's pretty much expected on Linux. The symbol is global and as such only one copy is being used, even though additional copies are loaded. To prevent that, one needs to link with -Bsymbolic. Perhaps this is the default on Mac OS X?

Comment: Thanks for the info about -Bsymbolic on Linux. I tested on Mac OS X, a symbol in a dynamic library is resolved within itself by default.

Comment: Thanks. I tried -Bsymbolic on Linux. The static variable is still created twice, but this time with two different memory locations. There is no more crash, but I wonder if there could be other sneaky bugs due to this duplicate variable.

Comment: Your library being loaded twice  has nothing to do with -Bsymbolic. Did you check the `ldd` command to see your library is *already* linked to the executable ?

Comment: @ConanLord Look at your glibc dump carefully, there are 2 copies of your library loaded from different path.

Answer (score 0):

I think the static initialization problem is solved if you hide your static variable in a static getter. So in the header you replace the static class variable

```
static MyClass myStaticObjOfMyClass;
```

with a static class function

```
static MyClass& getInstance();
```

and implement it in the cpp:

```
static MyClass& getInstance()
{
    static MyClass instance("myStaticObjOfMyClass", true);
    return instance;
}
```

The static object is initialized when `getInstance()` is called for the first time.